Python Script in Power BI: '{subplot_type}' at grid position ({row}, {col}) was not created with the secondary_y spec property set to True
Basically I am running Python script in Power Bi, I am very much new to Python. I installed Python correctly, with the correct libraries, copied code from this guy : https://github.com/BitcoinRaven/Bitcoin-Risk-Metric-V2/blob/main/BtcRiskMetricV2.py
adjusted it a bit,especially because I am using my own btcusd historical data, now I am having a plotting error.
Python script error.
ValueError:
Subplot with type '{subplot_type}' at grid position ({row}, {col}) was not created with the secondary_y spec property set to True. See the docstring for the specs argument to plotly.subplots.make_subplots for more information.
Can you help me fix the error I am getting to get this visual working?
I have attached download link to my pbix file for your assistance.
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtcHLsGn8YTua4NYHA73PvWaNQo?e=DSw59F
